Abort Controller does not cancel All the pending requests
In my project all the requests goes through a single fetch function. In that I am storing all the abort controller inside and global set. When the user swictches to another page I will call the global set and abort all fetch requests that are waiting for response. If a response is received for a req I remove its controller from the set.
But the problem is not all requests are cancelled. When I try only a fraction of requests are getting cancelled.
Fetch Req-
 const controller = new AbortController();
            const request = { urlString, controller };
            requests.activeRequests.add(request);
            const signal = controller.signal;

            fetch(urlString, {
                headers: headers,
                method: method,
                signal: signal,
                body: payload ? JSON.stringify(payload) : undefined,
                credentials: 'include' 
            }).then(async (response) => {
                if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 204) {
                    requests.activeRequests.delete(request);


and this code is executed when user switches to other page
requests.activeRequests.forEach((req)=>{
                req.controller.abort();
                requests.activeRequests.delete(req)
            })

Can someone help me understand why only some requests are cancelled, What am i doing wrong?

swictches to another page is this a SPA? or is there navigation actually taking place?

Navigation takes place in the application

you don't need to cleanup any requests, they'll be cancelled when the page unloads anyway - what is the issue with the requests not being cancelled?

I am sorry but I am confused here, in my app the url changes but the whole page won't reload. It means its SPA right?

It's your app, that's why I asked if it's an SPA or not. I don't know

In the network tab, I will able to see many requests in pending state even when url changes, so I guess my application is SPA. Sorry for the confusion, I thought if the URL changes its not SPA. I am new to web dev.

try this. Create a single AbortController, use it for all requests, then you only need a single call to controller.abort()

yeah I tried that, it cancels a few more request but not all requests are cancelled.

how many requests are pending?
